# VBA excel google search error

Tags: vba, excel, google-search

This topic is related to:
[VBA EXCEL GOOGLE LOOKUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829482/vba-excel-google-lookup)

Code ran successfully for first 741 records and returned the values and then I got an error.

I have noticed, that if I go to Google manually, it asked a CAPTCHA code.

Then I ran it again successfully for another 1271 records, then got blocked by Google.

Now Google blocks my requests, but I still need to do some testing and run a few more searches with 3-5k lists.

How can I avoid getting blocked? What changes should be done to code?

I am getting `error "91`, on this line:

> `Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0)`

Many thanks, your help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer, but what I have managed to find out is that Google blocks your searches (a.k.a. you and your script gets blank screens with no data to collect). That is what causes the `error 91`, because no data is being collected.

What saved me from getting blocked is a simple delay of loop:

`Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))`

If anyone found out any better or smarter ways, please share.

Kind regards,
Mr.D